# How Lebesgue integration solved the problem of changing the order of integration will change the value of integration?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Our professor started a course in measure theory by stating the problems of Riemann integration. One of the problems he\she stated is the following double integration:

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dy dx = \frac{-\pi}{4}$ but $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} dx dy =  \frac{\pi}{4}.$

**My question is:**

I have studied Lebesgue integration but still, until now it is not clear for me how Lebesgue integration solved the problem of changing the order of integration will change the value of integration? Is it by Fubini? if so, what was the solution?

Could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Looking at this in terms of Lebesgue integration does not "fix" the problem. The values of those iterated integrals won't change.  This is an example where switching the order of integration cannot be justified. Without absolute integrability, Fubini's theorem does not apply.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the iterated Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1 f(x,y)\, d\mu(y) \right) \, d\mu(x)$ is conceptually different than the integral of $f$ over $[0,1]^2$ with respect to the product measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  It may be you have not covered that. They could be equal and, again, Fubini gives a sufficient condition for that.

Comment: Could you please give me the link to the Fubini's theorem that does not apply without absolute integrability ? @RRL

Comment: For your second comment .... when are the 2 integrals mentioned in the first statement of your comment equal? @RRL

Comment: Are you speaking about the statement of Fubini theorem on pg.164 of "real and complex analysis " by Rudin? @RRL

Comment: Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) out first to understand Fubini's theorem.  I don't have that book.  It shows when the iterated integrals and double integral (with respect to product measure) are all equal.

Comment: but where is the absolute integrability in this version of Fubini theorem? @RRL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue integrable, then we would have $\int_{[0,1]^2} |f| < \infty$ and Fubini's theorem would guarantee that the interated integrals are equal.

However, in this case, using polar coordinates, we have

$$\{(r,\theta): 0\leqslant r \leqslant 1, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi/2\} \subset [0,1]^2,$$

and we see that

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{|x^2 - y^2|}{(x^2 + y^2)^2} \,dy\, dx > \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1\frac{|r^2\cos^2 \theta - r^2\sin^2 \theta|}{(r^2)^2}\, r \, dr \, d\theta \\= \int_0^1 \frac{dr}{r}\int_0^{\pi/2}|\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta| \, d\theta = \infty$$

Comment: why did you need to use polar coordinated here ?

Comment: @Smart20: I used polar coordinates because it is convenient. I show that $\int_{[0,1]} |f|$ dominates an integral  that is infinite and is easy to evaluate by changing to polar coordinates.